# Selecting latest row for user grouped by day help

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Hoping someone can help me here as I can't quite wrap my head around the best way to do this.

Im trying to SUM() some numbers from a JSON block, which I have working just fine, how ever there could be multiple records per day per user, and I only want to SUM the numbers of the latest record per day per user.

So, essentially using the record that matches MAX(created_at) per user, per day.

Some sample data

```
id  | user_id  | scan_id  | data           | created_at
1   | 1        | 100      | {"score": 40}  | 2015-11-06 22:15:27 
2   | 1        | 101      | {"score": 50}  | 2015-11-06 22:18:27
3   | 3        | 102      | {"score": 20}  | 2015-11-06 22:15:27 
4   | 3        | 103      | {"score": 70}  | 2015-11-06 22:12:27 
5   | 5        | 104      | {"score": 40}  | 2015-11-06 22:15:27 
6   | 6        | 105      | {"score": 10}  | 2015-12-06 22:15:27
```

In the above data,  I want to SUM the values from data->'score', but you can see the first 4 rows are from two users.  I only want to use the LATEST record in the SUM, so that would be record id's 2 and 3, but not 1 and 4 (as they were older than the other records)

Record 6, would fall under its own day as its on a different date.

So, this query works without getting the latest record,  I would like to know how to alter it to only use the latest record per user per day.

```
SELECT
 SUM((DATA ->> 'score')::integer) AS score, 
 count(*) as count,
 created_at::date
FROM
 scores
GROUP BY created_at::date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (not necessarily the most efficient) is to use the Postgres special `DISTINCT ON` modifier in a subquery, and then sum:

```
SELECT
    SUM(score) AS score, 
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    created_at_date
FROM
  ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, created_at::date) 
        created_at::date AS created_at_date, 
        (DATA ->> 'score')::integer AS score
    FROM 
        scores
    ORDER BY 
        user_id, created_at::date, created_at DESC
  ) AS g
GROUP BY 
    created_at_date ;
```

Tested at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bb162/1).

Comment: Thanks for the response, Will this ignore the outdated records though?

Comment: Looks like it does!  Awesome,  thanks ypercube!